# Shiny/R - Format the content of an input

Tags: r, input, shiny

How to format an input for telephone automatically (Ex. I'm typing the numbers and they appear between the parentheses and the dash: (xx) xxxx-xxxx)? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to enter the whole number without any spacing or formatting and **then** show it in (xx) xxxx-xxxx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input$phone_number` input will correct the format after 10 numbers are inserted.

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(rebus)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput('phone_number', 'Enter Phone Number (numbers without spaces)',placeholder = '(xx) xxxx-xxxx')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    
    observeEvent(input$phone_number, {
        
        value <- str_match(input$phone_number, capture('[0-9][0-9]') %R% optional(capture('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')) %R% optional(capture('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')))
        
        
        if(str_length(value[1, 1]) == 10 & !is.na(value[1,1])) {
            updateTextInput(session = session, 'phone_number', 'Enter Phone Number (numbers without spaces)', value = str_c('(', value[1, 2], ')', ' ', value[1, 3], '-', value[1,4]) )
            
        }
    })
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```